# If source code is only labelled "copyright" - what kinds of use, if any, are allowed?

Tags: copyright, unlicensed-code

The specific example I have in mind is the code posted along with a descriptive article at:

*[Lines with Arrows, Charles Petzold, April 18, 2007, New York, N.Y.](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/04/191200.html)*

In the article it simply says:

> © 2007, Charles Petzold

And in the code all files have a heading like this:

```
//------------------------------------------
// ArrowLine.cs (c) 2007 by Charles Petzold
//------------------------------------------
```

I didn't see or couldn't find any other statements about this on the website itself.

It seems to me that this code is not "licensed" in any explicit way (or is it?). But it does seems implicit that the author expects people to use it in some way (or why else even provide it?) - but maybe just by reading it.  But it is not clear whether any type of re-use either by modification or incorporation would (not) be allowed?

Comment: @curiousdannii thank you!